# Avoiding repeated select + options in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing a page that basically manages a list of things. Each thing is allocated to a person, and the allocation is done by a select box with options for each user in the system. (So changing the select box re-allocates the thing).

So say I have 100 objects in my table, and 150 users in my system. If I just do plain HTML, I'm going to have 15,000 option tags

I'm assuming there must be a better way of doing this. My thoughts so far are to just render the first  element, and then user jquery to copy the options to the other ones. Or the  other option I guess would be to have the options be populated by AJAX, though that is slightly awkward (I don't have an obvious place that the AJAX could get a list of users in the system from).

Any thoughts would be most welcome :)

Comment: Server side languages are your friend.

Comment: this is far too vague and not a properly put together question...edit post with some html with more specific description of the issue

Comment: Even if you solve this problem you're still going to end up with `<select>` lists of 100 and 150 elements, which are pretty much just as unusable. You might consider approaching this problem from a different angle - how might you redesign the interface to make it easier for your users to accomplish the task? If you were a user, how would *you* want to use the interface? Perhaps consider things like searching or autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

How about having some sort of popup for the selection. That way you would only need one instance of the `select` elemement along with its `options` tags.

So you would basically have each person in a list, a readonly input field and a small button next to it. If the user clicks this button, the popup appears and lets the user choose the "object". After closing the popup the selection is passed to the inputfield.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
<form …>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr id="editrow" style="display:none">
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td><td data-value="1">one</td></tr>
      <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td><td data-value="2">two</td></tr>
      <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td><td data-value="3">three</td></tr>
      <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td><td data-value="1">one</td></tr>
      <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td><td data-value="2">two</td></tr>
      <tr><td>col1</td><td>col2</td><td data-value="3">three</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

bind a click event handler to `tbody > tr > td` in which you

1. hide that `<tr>`
2. pull the data from its `<td>` and `data-value` attributes to populate the input elements in `#editrow`
3. if #editrow is in `<tbody>` show its preceeding `<tr>`
4. insert `#editrow` after the `<tr>` and make it visible
5. `.focus()` the input element of the `<td>` that got the click-event
6. make sure changes made within `#editrow` are updated in your `<tr>`'s `<td>`s accordingly (you should use delegated events for this. then you only need to create and bind the handlers once)

bind a submit event handler to the `<form>` in which you

1. walk through `tbody > tr` to build a data map (javascript object…)
2. prevent the form from being sent with `.preventDefault()`
3. submit the data-map you built in (1) using jQuery.ajax

Or you create `<input>`s for your `<td>`s and have the form submit naturally. bulding the map and sending it via ajax is less painful, as you don't need to manipulate hundreds of DOM elements.

This solution will not work without javascript. If it must work without, you won't get around flooding your DOM with hundreds of ever-repeating `<select>`s.